# Is the determinant of $\left( \begin{array}{rr} A & B\\ -B & A \end{array}\right) $ non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

I'd like to know if $$\left(
\begin{array}{rr} A & B\\
-B & A \end{array}\right)
$$
has non-negative determinant, where $A,B$ are $n \times n$ real matrices, not necessarily commuting.

I'm trying to show almost complex structure $J$ admits an orientation given by $\{e_1,\cdots ,e_n,Je_1,\cdots Je_n \}$. To show this orientation is well defined, I need to pick another such basis and show the transition matrix has positive determinant. And above is the transition matrix.

Thanks in advance for anyone who could help.

Note that in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369103/determinant-of-a-block-skew-symmetric-matrix) the answer is only provided when $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: Is $A$ invertible? Or does $A$ and $B$ commute?

Comment: A might not be invertible, and A might not commute with B. The only requirement is the big matrix is invertible.

Comment: @Jhin In fact, one can show that
$$
\det \pmatrix{A & B\\ - B & A} = |\det(A + iB)|^2
$$

Comment: In all the proofs below it is assumed $A$ is invertible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determinant of a block skew-symmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369103/determinant-of-a-block-skew-symmetric-matrix)

Comment: @kvantour If you compare these two questions carefully, they are still different. And none of the answers in that link proved the determinant is non-negative. So I suggested reopening the question.

Comment: Closely related: the matrix in question commutes with symplectic matrix $J=\left[\begin{matrix}\mathbf 0 & I_n\\-I_n & \mathbf 0\end{matrix}\right]$ so it has determinant $1$ per https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4261740/nonnegativity-of-the-determinant-of-a-commuting-matrix/. Conversely this post can be used as a lemma to prove the result in that link.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}$

As noted in the comment, taking determinants on both sides of the identity
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} I_{(n)} & iI_{(n)} \\ 0 & I_{(n)} \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ -B & A \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} I_{(n)} & -iI_{(n)} \\ 0 & I_{(n)} \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} A - iB & 0 \\ -B & A + iB \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}
yields
\begin{align*}
\det\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ -B & A \end{pmatrix} &= \det(A + iB)\det(A - iB) = \det(A + iB)\det(\overbar{A + iB}) \\
&= \det(A + iB)\overbar{\det(A + iB)} = |\det(A + iB)|^2 \geq 0,
\end{align*}
where we used the condition that $A$ and $B$ are real matrices, and for any $C \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, $\det(\overbar{C}) = \overbar{\det(C)}$, which can be easily verified by the definition of determinant.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a block-matrix of the form:

$$\mathbf{M}=\left(\begin{align}\mathbf{A}_{11} && \mathbf{A}_{12}  \\ \mathbf{A}_{21} && \mathbf{A}_{22} \end{align}\right)$$

then it's determinant can be computed in the following way. Define the two [Schur-complement matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement):

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{C}_1 &= \mathbf{A}_{11} − \mathbf{A}_{12}\mathbf{A}^{−1}_{22}\mathbf{A}_{21} \\
\mathbf{C}_2 &= \mathbf{A}_{22} − \mathbf{A}_{21}\mathbf{A}^{−1}_{11}\mathbf{A}_{12}
\end{aligned}
$$

And compute the determinant as:

$$\det\mathbf{M} =  \det\mathbf{A}_{22} \det\mathbf{C}_1=\det\mathbf{A}_{11} \det\mathbf{C}_2 $$

In case of the OP, this becomes:

$$\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{C}_1 = \mathbf{C}_2 = \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}^{−1}\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{I} - (\mathbf{A}^{−1}\mathbf{B})(\mathbf{A}^{−1}\mathbf{B})\right)$$

This implies that **if** the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible, the determinant is given by:

$$ (\det\mathbf{A})^2 \det\left(\mathbf{I} + (\mathbf{A}^{−1}\mathbf{B})(\mathbf{A}^{−1}\mathbf{B})\right) $$

We know that $(\det\mathbf{A})^2 > 0$ so all that remains is to show that $\det\left(1+X^2\right)\ge 0$

We can now write down the [Jordan decomposition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JordanMatrixDecomposition.html) of $\mathbf{X}$ as
$$\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{U}^{-1}\mathbf{JU}$$

with $\mathbf{J}$ an upper triangular matrix.

$$\det\left(1+X^2\right) = \det\left(\mathbf{U}^{-1}(\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{JJ})\mathbf{U}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+K_{ii}^2)\ge0$$

with $\mathbf{K}=\mathbf{JJ}$ which is [upper triangular](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2095108/539931)

Comment: $A$ may not be invertible.

Comment: @Zhanxiong this is mentioned in the text

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the determinant of
$$
C=\left(\begin{array}{rr}A&B\\-B &A\end{array}\right)
$$
is non-negative.

Hint. Assume first that $C$ is diagonalisable. It then suffices to show he following: If $\lambda$ is a negative eigenvalue of $C$, then its multiplicity is even.

This suffices because the product of all complex eigenvalues (is any) is positive.

Observe that, is $\lambda$ is a negative (in general, real) eigenvalue, corresponding to the eigenvector $(x,y)$, then $(y,-x)$ is also an eigenvector of $\lambda$, and linearly independent of $(x,y)$.

If $C$ is not diagonalisable, it is approximated by diagonalisable.

Comment: Thank you. I spend a lot of time trying to show there's no negative eigenvalue. But it turned out I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To show a non-negative determinant, it suffices to get the result by calculating the spectrum for a particularly simple case, then extend this to the more general case.

**lemma:**
$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
I & C\\
-C & I 
\end{bmatrix}\right)\geq 0$

using the Kronecker Product
$\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf 0 & C\\
-C & \mathbf 0 
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{matrix}\right] \otimes C$

with $\lambda_k$ being eigenvalues of $C$, the above has spectrum $\big\{i\cdot \lambda_1, -i\cdot \lambda_1, ..., i\cdot \lambda_n, -i\cdot \lambda_n\big\}$ thus
$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf 0 & C\\
-C & \mathbf 0 
\end{bmatrix}+ I_{2n}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^n \big(1 + i \cdot\lambda_k\big)\big(1 - i \cdot\lambda_k\big)$

since $\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf 0 & C\\
-C & \mathbf 0 
\end{bmatrix}+I_{2n}\right) $ is real all of its non-real eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs, and their product is positive.  Now consider purely real eigenvalues for the above matrix, their preimage under the Kronecker Product must have been purely imaginary eigenvalues of $C$.

Thus suppose we have $\lambda_j = a +i\cdot b= 0+i \cdot b$ and  $\lambda_{j+1}=-i\cdot b$ since $\lambda_j$ itself must have come in conjugate pairs since $C$ is real. Then bunching together their contribution to the determinant we have

$\big(1 + i \cdot\lambda_j\big)\big(1 - i \cdot\lambda_j\big)\big(1 + i \cdot\lambda_{j+1}\big)\big(1 - i \cdot\lambda_{j+1}\big)$
$=\big(1  - b \big)\big(1 + b\big)\big(1  + i \cdot (-i\cdot b)\big)\big(1  -i\cdot(-i\cdot b)\big)$
$=\big(1  - b\big)\big(1 + b\big)\big(1  + b\big)\big(1 - b \big)$
$=\big(1  - b\big)^2\big(1 + b\big)^2$
$\geq 0$

Thus
$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
I & C\\
-C & I 
\end{bmatrix}\right)\geq 0$ because it decomposes into the product of real non-negative terms and hence is itself $\geq 0$.

**main proof:**
if $\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
A & B\\
-B & A 
\end{bmatrix}\right) \lt 0$ then by continuity of the determinant
$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
A+\delta I & B\\
-B & A + \delta I 
\end{bmatrix}\right) \lt 0$
for all small enough $\delta \gt 0$

We'll show this is impossible.

Note that since $A$ has finitely many eigenvalues, $Z:=(A+\delta I)$ must be invertible for small enough $\delta$.  So after fixing some sufficiently small $\delta$, we have
$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
Z & B\\
-B & Z
\end{bmatrix}\right)$
$=  \det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
Z & \mathbf 0\\
\mathbf 0 & Z
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 
I & Z^{-1}B\\
-Z^{-1}B & I
\end{bmatrix}\right) $
$=  \det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
Z & \mathbf 0\\
\mathbf 0 & Z
\end{bmatrix}\right)\cdot \det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
I & Z^{-1}B\\
-Z^{-1}B & I
\end{bmatrix}\right) $
$= \det\big(Z\big)^2 \cdot \det\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
I & C\\
-C & I 
\end{bmatrix}\right) $
$\geq 0$

Answer (score -2):

We know:
det (X+Y) ≥ det(X) + det (Y)

this means: det(A^2 + B^2) ≥ det(A^2) + det(B^2)

which is ==> |A^2 + B^2| ≥ |A^2| + |B^2|; EQN 1

Using another property of matrices: |A|^n = |A^n|

Thus, RHS of EQN 1 = |A|^2 + |B|^2

Also, determinant of any nxn real matrix always exists and is a real number. So, square of a real number will always be non-negative!

Since RHS is a non-negative quantity and LHS is greater than equal to RHS, LHS WILL always be a non-negative quantity too!

Hope this addresses your concerns..

Comment: "We know: det (X+Y) ≥ det(X) + det (Y)": what if $X=-Y$ and $n$ is even?

Comment: the property still holds: since the symbol is greater than equal to and not just equal to. In this case the answer is 0 which is also non-negative (sing 0 is neither positive nor negative!)

Comment: but if I pick $X=I$ and $Y=-I$, I get $0 \geq 2$

Comment: |A| in matrices means determinant of A not absolute value of A. So det(-I) = -det(I)

Comment: when $n$ is even, $\text{det}(A) = \text{det}(-A)$

Comment: this mates rhs = det(I) -det(I) which =0

Comment: if n is even, say 2.. then LHS is also 2

Comment: no, when $n$ is even, $\text{det}(I) + \text{det}(-I) = 2 \text{det}(I)$

Comment: the LHS is $\text{det}(I+(-I)) = \text{det}(O) = 0$

Comment: there is A^n on both sides

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113488/discussion-between-priyanka-goradia-and-linalg).